# STS (Spring Tools Suite) 2.7.2 @RequestMappings View not displaying

Tags: user-interface, spring-mvc, controller

### Currently Using:

Spring Tools Suite v2.7.2

Spring Framework v3.0.5

### Sample Code in a controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value={ "/en/page", "/fr/page" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
```

### Steps to reproduce issue in STS:

- [Menu] Window -> Show View -> @RequestMappings
- [Project] Right Click -> Spring Tools -> Show RequestMappings

### Returns:

Javadoc content is missing or empty

### Question:

How can I populate all @RequestMappings to view all urls mapped in my web application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve, you must:

- Right click your project
- Spring Tools
- Add Roo Project Nature

Then:

- Right click your project
- Spring Tools
- Show @RequestMappings

It seems that the code must also compile before the mappings can be output in the IDE,

Cheers.

Comment: If your code has already built, it's worth cleaning the project.  The @RequestMappings display populated as the project re-built.

Comment: is there a way to search for a mapping? I tried ctrl+F on Windows. No go. I tried right-click, no search option. searching for "/controller1/action1" might not work if you have class level request mapping "/controller1" and method level request mapping "/action1".