# Why is "Show RequestMappings" under Spring Tools in STS not displaying anything?

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am running STS 3.6.1. All of our projects are Java Projects from a GIT Repository. I enabled Spring Project Nature and then choose Show RequestMappings from the Spring Tools menu but there is nothing displayed except for "Javadoc content is missing or empty". After reading [STS (Spring Tools Suite) 2.7.2 @RequestMappings View not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7448718/sts-spring-tools-suite-2-7-2-requestmappings-view-not-displaying) I started over and enabled Spring Project Nature, then rebuilt the entire project, then choose Show RequestMappings with the same result.

I have been able to do this in past projects. The only difference now is the use of Git instead of SVN. Could this be the issue? Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't add the Spring config files to the project. You do this by right-clicking on the project and selecting Properties. You then have to select the Spring config files.

Answer (score 0):

properties > spring > Beans Support > Scan > apply